# How to explain Fourier series in linear algebra context

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

I recently read about how the Fourier series is essentially a projection of a function $f$ onto the basis $\{1, \sin(x),\cos(x)\}$. Since a vector $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented as

$$w = \langle w,\textbf{i}\rangle\textbf{i} + \langle w,\textbf{j}\rangle\textbf{j}$$

is this analogous to the constant and Fourier coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ being the inner products $a_0=\langle f,1\rangle$, $b_n=\langle f,\sin nx\rangle$ and $a_n=\langle f,\cos nx\rangle$

If this is the case, why do we then take the infinite sum of each harmonic? Also, can this process be mimicked using any orthogonal basis?

Comment: In general, you need $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ for every positive integer $n$. And it's not a basis in the linear algebra sense, where every function would be expressible as a *finite* linear combination of basis elements. In order to represent most functions of interest, you need to allow infinite sums as well, which takes you into functional analysis and the notion of [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis).

Comment: The analogy in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is to pick an orthonormal basis $b_k$ and some point $x$. Then compute $f_k = \langle b_k , x \rangle$. Then the $f_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of $x$ with respect to the basis $b_k$.

Comment: It is the projection of $f$ onto $\{1,\sin x,\cos x,\sin 2x,\cos 2x,\cdots \}$, not the projection onto $\{1,\sin x,\cos x\}$.